# Can't find field reportModuleById on ROOT_QUERY object

Tags: apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have the following query:

```
export const ReportModuleProperties = gql`
  fragment ReportModuleProperties on ReportModule {
    __typename
    id
    content
    name
  }
`;

export const REPORT_MODULE_BY_ID = gql`
  query ReportModuleById($id: ID!) {
    reportModuleById(id: $id) {
      ...ReportModuleProperties
    }
  }
  ${ReportModuleProperties}
`;
```

At some point I write a Report Module to the cache:

```
apolloClient.writeQuery<ReportModuleById, ReportModuleByIdVariables>({
  query: REPORT_MODULE_BY_ID,
  data: { reportModuleById: reportModule },
  variables: { id: reportModule.id }
});
```

Then later I try to read it back from the cache using `readQuery`:

```
client.readQuery<ReportModuleById, ReportModuleByIdVariables>({
  query: REPORT_MODULE_BY_ID,
  variables: {id: moduleId}
})
```

I use `writeQuery` and `readQuery` the same way successfully throughout the application. But this time I see an error saying: 'Can't find field reportModuleById on ROOT_QUERY object'.

The strange part is that the data is actually in the cache:

[image: apollo-cache.png]

I try to wrap my head around this for days now, is there anything I miss here?